# How do I solve for the reaction force at the hinge

Tags: classical-mechanics

The question given is

> A uniform rod, of mass $m$ and length $2a$ smoothly hinged to a vertical wall is connected to a point on the wall above the hinge by a light inelastic string. Find the magnitude and direction of the force on the rod from the hinge.

The diagram given is

[image: Diagram 1]

I have constructed the forces on to the freebody diagram as such

[image: Diagram 2]

Using the vertical component of net force:
$$F_y=T \sin(20)-mg+R_V=0$$
$$\implies T\sin(20)=mg-R_V$$

Using the horizontal component of net force:
$$F_x=T \cos(20)-R_H=0$$
$$\implies T\cos(20)=R_H$$
$$\implies T=\frac{R_H}{\cos(20)}$$

Finding the moment around the hinge A:
$$\tau=T\sin(20)*2a\sin(50)-mg*a\sin(50)=0$$
$$\implies T\sin(20)=\frac{mg}{2}$$
$$\implies T=\frac{mg}{2\sin(20)}$$

Then, equating the two equations for $T\sin(20)$ I get:
$$\frac{mg}{2}=mg-R_V$$
$$\implies 2R_V=mg$$

Finally equating both equations for $T$:
$$\frac{mg}{2\sin(20)}=\frac{R_H}{\cos(20)}$$
$$\implies \frac{2R_V}{2\sin(20)}=\frac{R_H}{\cos(20)}$$
$$\implies \frac{R_V}{R_H}=\frac{\sin(20)}{\cos(20)}$$

And since $R_V,R_H$ are the vertical and horizontal components of the same force respectively, the $tan^{-1}$ of this ratio is equal to the angle between the resultant and the horizontal hence:

$$\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sin(20)}{\cos(20)})=20°$$

Which is wrong as the answer given in the book is that the angle is $82.7°$ and the reaction force is $0.474mg$, I am aware that this entire method is a hackjob but I have no clue on how to tackle this question properly, are the reaction forces I drew the problem or is it my working onwards?

How would I tackle this problem properly?

Comment: Why is there no tension in the rod? Your Tsin20 and Tcos20 makes me think that you think the rod is horizontal which it isn’t. Tcos20 could be a force parallel to the rod and Tsin20 perpendicular to the rod, if you want to do it that way. But they’re not vertical or horizontal forces - you seem to have completed ignored the $50 ^\circ.$ Something else you didn’t do is to take moments of the forces on the rod about $B$, the point where the string and rod meet. Doing so could simplify your task.

Comment: Also, either draw the force $T$, or draw the components of $T$, but don’t draw both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT for "How would I tackle this problem properly?"

There is a very clever method for tackling this type of problem. The key is **not** to split the forces up into components as you have done.

The point is that the rod is acted upon by just three forces.

These must add up to $0$ and so can be drawn head-to-tail to form a triangle and trig can then be used e.g. cosine rule/sine rule, ...

Even more usefully the three forces must pass through the same point! In your diagram, the forces of $mg$ and $T$ pass through a point, $P$ say,  on the rope directly over the middle of the rod. Then these two forces have no moment about $P$. But the moment of all the forces about $P$ must be zero and so the reaction must also pass through $P$ in order to have zero moment about $P$.

The entire question is thus reduced to the geometry of triangles.

Comment: Ah that’s clever and a nice answer!